# Unity - "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)

Tags: c#, unity

I'm using Unity5 right now. I got this error when try to setDestination.

```
"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)
CompleteProject.EnemyMovement:Update() (at Assets/_CompletedAssets/Scripts/Enemy/EnemyMovement.cs:30)
```

My code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Transform player;               // Reference to the player's position.
        PlayerHealth playerHealth;      // Reference to the player's health.
        EnemyHealth enemyHealth;        // Reference to this enemy's health.
        NavMeshAgent nav;               // Reference to the nav mesh agent.


        void Awake ()
        å{
            // Set up the references.
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
            playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
            enemyHealth = GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();
            nav = GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ();
        }


        void Update ()
        {
            // If the enemy and the player have health left...
            if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
            {
                // ... set the destination of the nav mesh agent to the player.
                nav.SetDestination (player.position);
            }
            // Otherwise...
            else
            {
                // ... disable the nav mesh agent.
                nav.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you baked a navmesh yet?

It looks like you're in the shooter tutorial.  The step right after creating the enemy and adding the NavMeshAgent to it includes creating a Nav Mesh to control it's movement.  You'll want to...

- go to Window->Navigation on the top menu (I have this window docked next to my inspector)
- Choose the Bake tab
- set up some params (The tutorial has Radius=0.75, Height=1.2 and Step Height=.0.1, and the rest of the settings from the tutorial are gone in Unity 5, as far as I can tell.
- Hit Bake at the bottom to bake the nav mesh.

This should run for a short time, and when it's done, try playing again and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following line is causing the issue:

```
nav.enabled = false;
```

Comment it out and try your code again!